# Activesupport and openssl: key must be 32 bytes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, openssl, activesupport

I've a rails 4.2.1 project that needs a gem with a dependency on openssl 2.1.1. My ruby version is 2.3.1. When I add the openssl gem, i get the following error for any of the page I load:

```
lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:100: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated

ArgumentError (key must be 32 bytes):
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:72:in `key='
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:72:in `_encrypt'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:58:in `encrypt_and_sign'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:527:in `[]='
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:110:in `set_cookie'
  rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:351:in `commit_session'
  rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `context'
  rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
```

Is there any workaround to make both of them compatible?

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the old keys I was succsscull using the code below to receive the key:

> attr_encrypted :attribute, key: ENV['MY_KEY'].bytes[0..31].pack( "c" * 32 )

Comment: Hum, i don't get it Chris. Where do you put that code? Sorry I missed your reply.

Comment: Insert the code in your model which requires the encrypted attribute. :attribute has to be replaced with your attribute name.

Comment: It's for cookies encryption, so I don't use it in a explicit way. It's under the hood. For now, I monkey patched the file key_generator.rb from activesupport with [this file](https://github.com/iwz/rails/blob/3fb47ffd9ab6c8248fc648a68650adde2c8dbd7d/activesupport/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb). It overwrites the default 64 key length.